# jQuery Checkbox multiselect and row select

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services

See the below code and screen. It's a configuration screen.

- while clicks the Fieldname checkbox it will select all the checkbox and if we remove a   check it will deselect all the checkbox.
- While clicks the Field1 checkbox. the child control will be select like (Add, Edit, Delete) and if we remove a check it will deselect checkbox.
- My question is how can I do this operation and how to get a value
- I'm using jQuery for this operation
- All the values are comes for database its a dynamic fields.

```
 <table width="100%">
        <tr style="background: #999; color: #FFF;">
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="field_name" value="yes" id="Checkbox1" />
                <label for="field_name" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Field Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Add" value="yes" id="Checkbox2" />
                <label for="default" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Add</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="yes" id="Checkbox3" />
                <label for="default" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Edit</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="delete" value="yes" id="Checkbox4" />
                <label for="default" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Delete</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="yes" id="field_1" />
                <label for="field_1" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Field 1</label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Add" value="yes" id="Checkbox5" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="yes" id="Checkbox6" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="delete" value="yes" id="Checkbox7" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row2">
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="yes" id="field_1" />
                <label for="field_1" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Field 2</label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Add" value="yes" id="Checkbox8" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="yes" id="Checkbox9" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="delete" value="yes" id="Checkbox10" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: welcome to SO. please do not use words like "urgent" and all. you may get negative votes for that

Comment: What have you tried and what doesn't work? We deal with broken code here, not requests.

Comment: i tried with check all its working. i don't know how to select a particular row?

Comment: What everybody is trying to get to, @sathishkumar, is that we don't want to do the work *for* you.  We'd be happy to help you figure things out if you show us something you've tried.  Until then, you haven't given us anything to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give an id to your table like `id="mytable"` and use this code

```
$("#mytable tr:first input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    var selector = $("#mytable td:first-child input[type=checkbox]")
    if (this.checked) {
        $(selector).attr("checked", "checked");
    }
    else {
        $(selector).removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/ETKqx/

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("table tr:first input[type=checkbox]").click(function () {
            var selector = "input[type=checkbox]:[name=" + $(this).attr("name") + "]";
            $(selector).attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
        });
    });
</script>
 <table width="100%">
        <tr style="background: #999; color: #FFF;">
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="field_name" value="yes" id="Checkbox1" />
                <label for="field_name" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Field Name</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Add" value="yes" id="Checkbox2" />
                <label for="default" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Add</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="yes" id="Checkbox3" />
                <label for="default" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Edit</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="delete" value="yes" id="Checkbox4" />
                <label for="default" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Delete</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row1">
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="field_name" value="yes" id="field_1" />
                <label for="field_1" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Field 1</label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Add" value="yes" id="Checkbox5" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="yes" id="Checkbox6" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="delete" value="yes" id="Checkbox7" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row2">
            <td>
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="field_name" value="yes" id="field_1" />
                <label for="field_1" class="checkboxlabel">
                    Field 2</label>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Add" value="yes" id="Checkbox8" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="yes" id="Checkbox9" />
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="delete" value="yes" id="Checkbox10" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```